# Controller Not Found When Defined with module.controller() Method

Tags: module, controller, angularjs

### Problem

My controller is not being found when I create the controller using `module.controller()`.  I get the following exception:

```
Error: Argument 'HelpCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

### Detail

I am refactoring my controllers.js file, breaking out each controller into its own separate file.  I'm doing this by doing the following:

#### A typical controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('idalinkApp')
  .controller('HelpCtrl', function(){

        //insert awesome controlling code here
    });
```

My `application.js`'s bootstrap module is the same as the module name above' `idalinkApp`:

```
var idalinkModule = angular.module('idalinkApp', [ 'idalinkResources', 'idalinkFilters',
    'idalinkDirectives', 'ngSanitize','ui','memberService', 'formStatusService' ]);...
```

And here's my `ng-app` declaration in my index.html page:

```
... <body id="ng-app" data-ng-app="idalinkApp" class=" login idalink-todo idalink-hide idalink-altnav releaseOne"> ...
```

I've also confirmed that the `help.js` file containing my HelpCtrl is being loaded in the browser.

### Plea

Any ideas?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Are you sure your bootsrap runs before your controller declaration? Would you post a Plunker?

Comment: do you have 2 module declarations with same name or is code provided just duplicated? If so, second is overwriting first

Comment: `idalinkApp` is getting declared twice, I think you need to rename one of them and let the one injected to the other.

Comment: CaioToOn, based on the above code, it does look right.  I've gotten it working now.  The important takeaway from this is that angular.module() does two things based on the # of args.  You create a module when you call `angular.module('ModuleName',[])` -- note the array arg.  You reference an already created module when you call `angular.module('ModuleName')`.  charlietfl, you may have been right when I was overwriting.